# How do I earn the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges?

Tags: support, badges

The description is weird and hard to understand. The description for Tenacious is

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total

Unsung Hero is similar, just a little harder.

What are the requirements to get these badges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requirement is a little weird to read, but the requirements for Tenacious can be parsed out as follows:

- Have more than 5 answers with +0 score that are accepted
- These 5 or more answers constitute 20% or more of your total number of answers

For Unsung Hero, the requirements are similar, but harder:

- Have more than 10 answers with +0 score that are accepted
- These 10 or more answers constitute 25% or more of your total number of answers

For example, if you have 6 answers that are +0 and accepted, and 29 total answers, you should obtain a Tenacious badge, since those 6 constitute 20.6% of your answer count. As you can imagine, this is extremely hard to do: [only 6 users](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/183/tenacious) have ever obtained the Tenacious badge, and [only 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/unsung-hero) have obtained Unsung Hero on Arqade.

Comment: Good luck getting a Platinum Trophy on StackExchange :)

Comment: *He's an unsung hero, got stars in his eyes*